# Found '1.8' instead. Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to compile my code with JDK 1.8 , but While changing java compiler to 1.8 , I was getting an error in cmd : Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.8' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.

Comment: Not sure what you want. Solution is literally provided in the error message

Comment: i want to compile my code with jdk 1.8 , but due to this error i am not able to compiler. plz help.

Comment: my code contains some methods which are included in java 8 not in older version.

Comment: Java 1.8 will not work with Eclipse I think. You have to install Android Studio.

Comment: Having the same problem right now

Comment: i have compile java code with eclipse and it is working perfectly , but i want to run that java classes with android.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you will not able to use Java 1.8 at android projects in Eclipse, take a look what documention says:

> Support for Java 8 language features requires a new compiler called
> Jack. Jack is supported only on Android Studio 2.1 and higher. So if
> you want to use Java 8 language features, you need to use Android
> Studio 2.1 to build your app.
>
> You don’t have to do anything differently to use Jack — just use your
> standard makefile commands to compile the tree or your project. Jack
> is the default Android build toolchain for M.

About Java 8 and Android: [Use Java 8 Language Features](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html)

To install Android Studio: [Android Studio - The Official IDE for Android](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)

To import your project: [Import Eclipse Projects to Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html)

To know more about Jack compiler: [The Jack toolchain](https://source.android.com/source/jack.html)